# Verify thread-safety MySQLdb (Python) prior to Trac installation

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, mysql-python

I'm trying to install Trac manually for the first time. I don't want to use a one-click-installer like Bitmani, I want to learn how to install Trac manually, so I'm following the instructions carefully. I'm installing it in a Windows localhost for now, before installing it in a Linux environment.

As I follow the instructions carefully, I needed to install Python+MySQLDb, and I read this:

> **thread-safety is important**
> (...) verify that it is thread-safe by calling MySQLdb.thread_safe() from a standalone Python script (i.e., not under Apache). If the stand-alone test reports that MySQLdb is indeed thread-safe (...)

I've just installed [MySQLDb 1.2.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) and I'd like to verify this. I've Googled but I haven't found an example about this, and I have no idea about Python. How can I verify if I've got a thread-safe installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command.  If you get `1` in the output, your installation is threadsafe.

```
python -c "import MySQLdb ; print MySQLdb.thread_safe()"
```

Comment: I tried but I've got this error: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, I've just replaced `'` with `"` and I've got `1`, so I've now verified it. THANKS!!!

Comment: @Metafaniel haha, I was just going to suggest that, you're too fast :)  Glad it worked for you!